# Handler doesn't stop on button click

Tags: java, android, handler

I have a runnable which starts an activity and a handler, which lets the runnable repeat after 5 seconds. However, i implemented a "stop button" which should stop that handler, but somehow it doesn't work. 
I would appreciate some help why it doesn't stop the loop.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button callBtn;
    private Button stopBtn;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable redial=new Runnable(){

    @Override public void run(){Intent callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:+49888888"));startActivity(callIntent);

    }};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
        stopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        // add PhoneStateListener for monitoring
        MyPhoneListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneListener();
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        // receive notifications of telephony state changes
        telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        callBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                redial.run();
            }
        });

        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                handler.removeCallbacks(redial);
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyPhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean onCall = false;


        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // phone ringing...
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, incomingNumber + " calls you",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    // one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "on call...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //because user answers the incoming call
                    onCall = true;
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    // in initialization of the class and at the end of phone call

                    // detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                    if (onCall == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "restart app after call",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // restart our application
                        Intent restart = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().
                                getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                        restart.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(restart);

                        onCall = false;

                        handler.postDelayed(redial, 5000);


                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Simple calling redial.run() will just run that method once and nothing else. To actually use the Runnable you need to use one of the post() methods of the Handler class.

Comment: You are not using handler properly. You should call handler.post to the runnable in order to remove callback.